# Redux Form Wizard, button to send json field data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, wizard

When using Redux Form Wizard on second page, I have two buttons asking user gender, Male or Female.

Goal: When user clicks on Male or Female button, that button sends that json information to the WizardFormThirdPage.

Here is a Sandbox modified from the [ReduxForm website Wizard example at this link.](https://redux-form.com/7.0.2/examples/wizard/)

I have an issue:

- the button data of "Male" or "Female" doesn't save in the store (not dispatched) unlike the other "Working Radio Button" under the buttons.

Here is the relevant files too in [gist link](https://gist.github.com/eliaahadi/e79504659656f739ee2c7ab7823d6d45) and below. I'm using VS Code for my editor.

Any thoughts? Thank you!

**WizardFormSecondPage.js**

```
class Test extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      buttonText1: false,
      buttonText2: false
    };
  }

  changeTextColor(value) {
    if (value === 1)
      this.setState({
        buttonText1: !this.state.buttonText1,
        buttonText2: false
      });
    else
      this.setState({
        buttonText1: false,
        buttonText2: !this.state.buttonText2
      });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      input: { value, onChange }
    } = this.props;
    console.log("this props shows blah", this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          type="button"
          className={this.state.buttonText1 ? "orangeTextButton" : ""}
          onClick={() => this.changeTextColor(1)}
        >
          Male
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className={this.state.buttonText2 ? "orangeTextButton" : ""}
          onClick={() => this.changeTextColor(2)}
        >
          Female
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const renderError = ({ meta: { touched, error } }) =>
  touched && error ? <span>{error}</span> : false;

const WizardFormSecondPage = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, previousPage } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label>What is your gender?</label>
        <div>
          <Field name="sex" component={Test} value="male" />

          <label>
            <Field name="sex" component="input" type="radio" value="female" />{" "}
            Working Radio Button
          </label>
          <Field name="sex" component={renderError} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" className="previous" onClick={previousPage}>
          Previous
        </button>
        <button type="submit" className="next">
          Next
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: "wizard", //Form name is same
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
  forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true, // <------ unregister fields on unmount
  validate
})(WizardFormSecondPage);
```

**W2.scss**

```
  button{
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 15px;
  }

  .blackTextButton{
    /* background-color: white; */
    color: black;
  }

  .orangeTextButton{
    /* background-color: white; */
    color: orange;
  }
```

Comment: You can check the handleSubmit functionality of redux-forms
[link] https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/faq/handlevson.md/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a state for `Test` component probably. Instead, you're able to create a new stateless component:

```
const Test = ({ input: { value, onChange } }) => (
  <div>
    <button
      type="button"
      className={value === 'male' ? 'orangeTextButton' : ''}
      onClick={() => onChange('male')}
    >
      Male
    </button>
    <button
      type="button"
      className={value === 'female'  ? 'orangeTextButton' : ''}
      onClick={() => onChange('female')}
    >
      Female
    </button>
  </div>
);
```

Example code uses the Redux Form Field API. `onChange` callback will update your form's state with `male`/`female` values, so in the parent form you can retrieve this value on form submit as well as other fields (or use a selector).

I'm not sure, I've got the idea fully, but this should work in your case. Hope it helps.